# How do I compute the gradient of a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors

From [this](http://xavier.amatriain.net/pubs/karatzoglu-recsys-2010.pdf) paper, we have three matrices $U\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d_U}$, $M\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times d_m}$, $C\in \mathbb{R}^{c\times d_C}$ and a tensor $S\in \mathbb{R}^{d_U \times d_M \times d_C}$, such that $$F_{ijk} = S ~\times_U~ U_{i* } ~\times_M ~ M_{j*} ~ \times_C ~ C_{k*} $$

The original tensor $F$ is basically a 3-dimensional matrix, decomposed into factors.

The first question I have is how do I compute $F_{ijk}$ from the equation above (I'm not familiar with tensor calculus)?

Later on in the paper, gradient descent is used to derive the factors $S, U, M, C$. The update equations are of the form:
$$ U_{i*} \longleftarrow U_{i*} - \eta \lambda_UU_{i*} - \eta \partial _{U_{i*}} l(F_{ijk}, Y_{ijk})   $$

and similarly for the remaining matrices and tensor $S$ updates. Assuming $l(\cdot)$ is Euclidean distance, how do I compute the last term in $U_{i*}$ update?